# In Digital Multimeter note accuracy in digits

Tags: digital-logic, multimeter

I have digital Multimeter noted in the multimeter accurcy is range 0 - 1000v at 0.2% +30 digits in this range what is 30 digits?

Comment: I don't understand what's being asked. Exactly what is written on your multimeter? "0 - 1000v at 0.2% +30 digits"?

Comment: Question is clear to those with the knowledge to answer.

Comment: @Chris: The question is so poorly worded that it is not clear.  Perhaps English is not the OP's first language, but I expect this would be a runon sentence in any language.

Comment: @OlinLathrop the question is very clear to those who care to understand it.  Those who do not care or do not wish to be of assistance need not concern themselves.

Answer (score 6):

+/- 30 digits indicates the 'absolute error' of the value displayed means that what ever value you read on the display, you have to add / subtract max. 30 from the display value to find the range the actual value is in.

For example your multimeter shows 10.00V then:

- add 30 ticks to find the upper limit 10.30V
- subtract 30 ticks to find the lower limit 09.70V

So your actual value will be between 9.70V and 10.30V

This also illustrates why you have to choose a measuring range that fits the measured value best. If you choose a too high range, the absolute error will render your measurement completely useless. Look at this example:

Your display reads 00.10V:

- add 30 => 0.40V
- subtract 30 => -0.20V

Which is an entirely useless result, the actual value ranging from -200mV to +400mV due to bad range and its absolute error. In such a case choose a better (lower) range.

---

You didn't ask about it, but your relative error was 0.2%. Back to the 9.70V - 10.30V example:

- The lower limit will be 9.70V - 0.2% = 9.68V
- The higher limit will be 10.30V + 0.2% = 10.32V

So when you read 10.00V on your multimeter, the actual value will range somewhere between 9.68V and 10.32V.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the word used is "counts", not "digits". It's a reference to the counter used in the typical dual-slope ADC commonly used in digital multimeters.

There are basically two limits to the accuracy of such a meter: The precision of the components used in the analog side of things gives you a percentage-of-reading (or percentage-of-range) error, and the accuracy of the timing circuits on the digital side gives you the ±counts error.

The possible error on any particular measurement is generally going to be the larger of these two numbers.